# How to deal with mail templates?

Tags: civimail, message-templates

I'm administering a site with some mail templates. They contain pretty much logic, and it is easy to make mistakes when making sure that both the text and the html version displays exactly the same information.

I have considered disabling the text version, but I don't know how. After all, very few don't have support for html in their email client today. As a workaround I have thought of just copying everything from the html to the text.

Any ideas of how to handle this properly?

Comment: have you tried just removing the content from the text version?

Comment: That was an extremely good solution and it works like a charm. Thank you. It seems like if you remove everything, it will automatically create a text version from the html version.

Comment: Great. I will add as an Answer. Can you please Accept (tick) this answer. SE likes to know that there is an Answer for each Question

Answer (score 1):

One option is to remove the content from the text version. CiviCRM will then construct a simplified version of the html for users who specify text only.